# New Gmail and Chrome desktop notifications

Tags: gmail, notifications

Is it me or the Chrome desktop notification system is broken in the new Gmail? I get the notifications for Chat, but not for new emails.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not you...I have the same problem here.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are allowing chrome to show desktop notifications? As this functionality is working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have Gmail open in a tab in Chrome to actually receive the Gmail notifications. They work for me.

Comment: Yes, I know; that's not the point. The point is that they are not working in the look.

Comment: What do you mean in the look? @Alex

Comment: The [new layout design](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/gmails-new-look.html) they are rolling out.

Comment: I'm on the layout and still get them.